# Save JSON straight to database qt

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, json, qt

I have been using code from the [Qt Save game Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html) to create a JSON file.
I want to store these files in my MS SQL Server 2016 Database.

```
bool SurveyJson::saveSurvey(SurveyJson::SaveFormat saveFormat, QString surveyName) const
{
    QFile saveFile(saveFormat == Json
                   ? "C:/Surveys/" + surveyName +".json"
                   : "C:/Surveys/" + surveyName +".dat");

    if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        qWarning("Couldn't open save file.");
        return false;
    }


    QJsonObject surveyObject;
    write(surveyObject);
    QJsonDocument saveDoc(surveyObject);
    saveFile.write(saveFormat == Json
                   ? saveDoc.toJson()
                   : saveDoc.toBinaryData());

    return true;
}
```

This code snippit saves it as a file in C:/Surveys/survayName.json
and I am able to save it to my database using this query.

```
INSERT INTO files
SELECT 'json' As FileType, *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Surveys\test.JSON', SINGLE_BLOB)
as X
```

How do I skip this step, and save it straight to the database?

Comment: You shouldn't save the JSON into the database but rather the data.

Comment: It's quite hard to debug JSON files in a DB, and creates unnecessary complexity, since you're not able to use SELECTs on the data inside the JSON

Answer (score 0):

**Saving raw files / text is highly discouraged**

It's quite hard to debug JSON files in a DB, and creates unnecessary complexity, since you're not able to use SELECTs on the data inside the JSON

Create a table where each parameter is a column. It allows easier maintenance, and insert all the parameters in the table (or store them in another way, but as values, not as JSON String).

**About your question**

Have a look at [QtSQL](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtsql-index.html%20%22QtSQL)

It provides an API for most DBs, and SQL Server is supported through the ODBC Driver.

If you really want to save the raw JSON String, just save the `saveDoc.toJson()` string inside your DB with an INSERT, using the QtSQL API (link above)